# vim script, onkeypress equivalent

Tags: javascript, vim

I have a vim plugin called as [`files.vim`](https://github.com/sincebasic/files.vim)
This does list all files and let you search and open it.

I want to improve this by accepting your key stroke, resulting filtering search result.
I can use `input()` method to accept a word from user. However I want it to read the input when user types it, like the same as javascript `onkeypress`

Searched vim help, still no luck.

Is there a way for this?

Comment: you may want to take look the codes of Ctrl-P plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `getchar()`.

> Get a single character from the user or input stream.

### Alternative

Some plugins (e.g. [FuzzyFinder - buffer/file/command/tag/etc explorer with fuzzy matching](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)) use a different approach: They open a scratch buffer programmed with a custom insert-mode completion. The completion function will be invoked automatically on each keypress, and the plugin is then able to update the list of matches. Inside the buffer, keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd> are also hooked, so that when the completion is done, the scratch buffer is automatically closed and the result retrieved. Actually, FuzzyFinder can be extended with your own data source; it might be worthwhile to look into that instead of re-implementing something similar.

Comment: thanks, getchar() does not have a cursor though. I wish there was a callback function for search, `/`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorMovedI) detecting Cursor Movement ?